# How can I get my 13" MacBook Pro to detect the NVMe m.2 drive that I installed?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, ssd

Today I installed a **Samsung 970 Evo 1TB** on my 13" mid 2014 MacBook Pro. I used an adapter that is not the [small sintech one](http://eshop.sintech.cn/ngff-m2-pcie-ssd-card-as-2013-2014-2015-macbook-ssd-p-1139.html) that everyone else seems to be using but is a different sintech [similar one](http://eshop.sintech.cn/ngff-m2-pcie-ssd-card-as-2013-2014-2015-macbook-ssd-p-1229.html) with a full length pcb.

[image]

[image]

Once I went into the system recovery mode (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>), and went into Disk Utility to detect and recover my backup onto the new SSD, but it didn't show up.

Things I have tried:

- Moving SSD around in adapter.
- Moving the adapter around.
- Adjusting both connections.
- Using the Apple provided screw and different combinations of pressure.

I might be, but hopefully didn't, mess up the adapter choice or installed it wrong, but I just want to fix soon to dual boot since I only have 128 GB.

Comment: In Disk Utility, try erasing the SSD first.

Comment: Same person here but I logged in through google instead of using a guest account. How do I erase the ssd?
I have do this multiple times with other drives but my main problem is that macOS doesn't recognize the drive at all. It doesn't show up in `diskutil list` or disk utility.

Comment: Did you follow these instructions from the web page?  http://pc-adapter.net/files/how%20to%20install%2010.13%20MAX%20OS%20in%20NGFF%20NVME%20SSD.pdf

Comment: Make sure you are running macOS 10.13.6 or later, since that is the first version of the OS that supports NVMe drives.

Comment: I had to use 10.14+ to detect my NVMe drive (in a 2014 iMac)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure in disk utility you have shown all disks/drives/volumes and not just volumes as is the default view.... A bare unformatted drive is usually not shown especially in High Sierra+ where they introduced APFS because of the new file structure. Click on the gear or down arrow and show all devices in the left side are of disk utility and see if you can then see the nvme, click on the very root of the drive not a volume and format it to apfs. If you don't see it to do this, then you have a bad adapter probably and should buy the one that's most recommended. Nvme support isn't as great as I'd hoped on my 2014 MBP either. I fixed the slow to restart and sleep issue but the system still doesn't recognize it at boot for almost 20 seconds (even after selecting it as the startup disk as many have suggested, that didn't help a thing for me) it simply takes several seconds to see it unless I boot and hold option key and then select it which is much faster to show it but still a pain to have to do. I actually pulled mine and use it in my m. 2 slot on my Windows Z390 Mobo instead as I restart and or sleep the Mac alot in my work (I'm in and out of car a lot) so it really wasn't practical for me. But try showing all devices in the left pane.... It should be there if you don't have a bad adapter.

the attached is what you want to see in order to do the proper formatting etc.

[image: see ALL volumes]

Comment: Hi! I have same situation. Evo 970 1tb and MacBook Pro 15 mid 2015. It won't find any drive and in disk utility I don't have an option to show all devices. Did they remove it? Because when I'm on my old drive and boot in recovery it has that drop-down option..

Comment: That's how it looks like https://photos.app.goo.gl/3R87YYqiS95SvbUk9

Comment: Ok just in case someone is struggling like me: try CMD + alt(option) +R :) the menu is showing correctly

Answer (score 1):

you will need to set it up with high Sierra 10.13.6 and it will recognize it

Comment: Catalina is a later build, that won't work?

Answer (score 0):

I'll share my experience. There was an update issue with my Macbook Pro 2015 (Mid) and the NVME drive was suddenly dead. Hence I purchased a new one along with the PCI-E X2 to M.2 Converter. Initially at Startup internet recovery ( <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> ) was not showing up the NVME SSD once after using an SSD Enclosure and initializing/Formatting it to APFS as well. Then I created a bootable USB Monterey and booted it as the startup disk and it worked.

Thanks to all the above people.